# Why is SciPy's uniform_filter function throwing a ValueError from its _get_output subroutine?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, imagefilter

I'm trying to understand the following functions particularly the following line from `uniform_filter`:

`output, return_value = _ni_support._get_output(output, input)`

I'm not sure I quite understand how `_get_output` in `uniform_filter` appears to return both an `output` and `return_value` when it appears to just return one `output` of type  ndarray in the `_get_output` function. Additionally when I run, I keep getting thrown a `"ValueError: too many values to unpack"` from that line. Can somebody please explain to me how this works, what's going wrong, and possibly how to fix?

```
    def uniform_filter(input, size=3, output=None, mode="reflect",
                       cval=0.0, origin=0):
        """Multi-dimensional uniform filter.
        Parameters
        ----------
        %(input)s
        size : int or sequence of ints
            The sizes of the uniform filter are given for each axis as a
            sequence, or as a single number, in which case the size is
            equal for all axes.
        %(output)s
        %(mode)s
        %(cval)s
        %(origin)s
        Notes
        -----
        The multi-dimensional filter is implemented as a sequence of
        one-dimensional uniform filters. The intermediate arrays are stored
        in the same data type as the output. Therefore, for output types
        with a limited precision, the results may be imprecise because
        intermediate results may be stored with insufficient precision.
        """
        input = numpy.asarray(input)
        output, return_value = _ni_support._get_output(output, input)
        sizes = _ni_support._normalize_sequence(size, input.ndim)
        origins = _ni_support._normalize_sequence(origin, input.ndim)
        axes = list(range(input.ndim))
        axes = [(axes[ii], sizes[ii], origins[ii])
                               for ii in range(len(axes)) if sizes[ii] > 1]
        if len(axes) > 0:
            for axis, size, origin in axes:
                uniform_filter1d(input, int(size), axis, output, mode,
                                 cval, origin)
                input = output
        else:
            output[...] = input[...]
        return return_value

    # from _ni_support.py   
    def _get_output(output, input, shape=None):
        if shape is None:
            shape = input.shape
        if output is None:
            output = numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=input.dtype.name)
        elif type(output) in [type(type), type(numpy.zeros((4,)).dtype)]:
            output = numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=output)
        elif isinstance(output, string_types):
            output = numpy.typeDict[output]
            output = numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=output)
        elif output.shape != shape:
            raise RuntimeError("output shape not correct")
        return output
```

Comment: FYI: That code was changed about five months ago in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8461; the `_get_output` support function now has a single return value.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you so much! I didn't realize the change. Although I am curious how it worked in the first place before the code update...